# Making a reponsive map

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a responsive map.
Here is the code I have:

```
<div class="maincontent">
<div class="map-holder">
 <div class="map">
 <div class="row1">
   <div class="part1">
   </div>
 </div>
 ....
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 .maincontent{position:relative;}
 .map-holder{width:100%; height:100% position:absolute; left:0; top:0; overflow:hidden;}
 .map{width:2000px; height:2000px; position:absolute; left:0; top:0;}
 .row1{display:block;}
 .part1{background-img:"path to a part of the map";}
```

All the parts of the map are within the "map" div.
I want to show a small part of the map by adjusting the size of "map-holder".
But when I set the height and width to a number like 200px, It is obviously not responsive. And when I use percent to adjust the size, nothing is shown in the browser.

Please Help me with this!
How can I adjust the size of "map-holder", so that It remains responsive across different screen resolutions?

Comment: What are the roles of "row1" and "part1"? I am having a hard time understanding why you have so many nested divs.

Comment: "row1" is the first row of the parts of the map! I wanted to keep all parts in one block so I added this div. And "part1" is the first part of the map, the other parts are in other dives with classes like, "part2", "part3", so on.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "parts". The map is one big canvas that you add stuff to. Nothing gets put into separate `div` tags to create the map.

Comment: My method is different for implementing the map! I have sliced the image of a map and put them in separate divs

Comment: Are you using Google Static Maps API or the regular Google Maps API?

Comment: I'm not using Google Maps at all. I'm trying to make a map from scratch!

Comment: You used the tag *google-maps*. You'll probably need to provide more detail on how you are creating this "map" then. I don't understand by your code and small explanation what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: BTW you are missing an opening "  in `<div class=maincontent">`

Comment: Sorry, I removed the tag. I will edit my question and add more details soon.

Answer (score 0):

I remember first starting with Google Maps API and having trouble with any little problem with the CSS or the `divs` surrounding it would make it disappear. I have this code:

HTML:

```
<div id="mapWrap">
    <div id="map-canvas">
    </div>
</div>
```

Where the map is placed inside `map-canvas`.

CSS:

```
html, body{
      height:100%;
      width:100%;
    }

    #mapWrap{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    padding-bottom: 100%; /* Ratio 16:9 ( 100%/16*9 = 56.25% ) */
}
#map-canvas{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

And this gives me a perfectly responsive map on a web page by itself. Then, all I would need to do is add content around it.

I will need to play with your specific case more to understand what's going on with it. But maybe this code will help for now.